# EF6 (code first), MVC, Unity, and a service layer without a repository

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My application is using SQL Server 2012, EF6, MVC and Web API.

It's also using a repository and assorted files such as:

```
DatabaseFactory.cs
Disposable.cs
IDatabaseFactory.cs
IRepository.cs
IUnitOfWork.cs
RepositoryBase.cs
UnitOfWork.cs
```

We already use a service layer between our controllers and the repository
for some complicated business logic. We have no plans EVER to change to a different database and it has been pointed
out to me that the recent thinking is that EF6 is a repository so why build 
another repository on top of it and **why have all of the files I have above**.

I am starting to think this is a sensible approach.

Does anyone know of any examples out there that implement EF6 without a 
repository, **with a service layer**. My search on the web has revealed many 
complex code examples that seem over complicated for no reason at all.

My problem is also when using a Service Layer then where do I put:

```
context = new EFDbContext()
```

In the controller, the service layer or both ? I read that I can do this with dependancy injection. I already use Unity as an IOC but I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: Putting the context on the controller would beat the purpose of having a service layer in the first place.

Comment: @EfrainReyes - but what about the case of very simple tasks such as a simple PUT, POST or DELETE (these are mainly Web API controllers).  Should these not be handled in the controller. If I push these out to a service layer it seems like a lot of additional coding. I hope for your advice on this. Thanks

Comment: It's not a lot more code. All you'd have to do is place those simple tasks on the service layer rather than on the controller itself, and have the controller handle the service. Just as a repository layer is a safeguard in case you change your database engine, a service layer is a safeguard in case you change your web service framework. Maybe your employer/client decides that they want to switch to RESTSharp, WCF or ServiceStack. If your tasks are on the controllers themselves, you'll have to rewrite them. If they're on the service layer, you just have to call the corresponding methods.

Answer (score 7):

Entity Framework *IS* already a Unit of Work pattern implementation as well as a generic repository implementation (DbContext is the UoW and DbSet is the Generic Repository).  And I agree that it's way overkill in most apps to engineer another UoW or Generic Repository on top of them (besides, GenericRepsitory is considered to be an anti-pattern by some).

A Service layer can act as a concrete repository, which has a lot of benefits of encapsulating data logic that is specific to your business needs.  If using this, then there is little need to build a repository on top of it (unless you want to be able to change your backend service technology, say from WCF to WebApi or whatever..)

I would put all your data access in your service layer.  Don't do data access in your controller.  That's leaking your data layer into your UI layer, and that's just poor design.  It violates many of the core SOLID concepts.

But you do NOT need an additional UnitOfWork, or other layers beyond that in most cases, unless your apps are very complex and intended to work in multiple environments...

Comment: Indeed the Entity Framework is an implementation of the Unit of Work pattern, but the implementation is internal. There is nothing preventing external objects working with separate `DbContext` contexts. Should multiple services use separate contexts where their operations should be enrolled in a single transaction, the value from the `Unit of Work` pattern is lost. A concrete instance could be passed from the controller, where the request is kicked off and disposed, amongst all the services, but to my mind that isn't as clean.

Comment: I up'ed your comment on my answer, as I tend to agree with you mostly, but apparently not always :)

Comment: @ChrisHardie - How about using IOC to create the context? I read a lot of people talking about that but have yet to find a good example.

Comment: @SamanthaJ `DbContext` doesn't implement an interface for its most useful methods, so I don't think a Unity container would provide much value. Even if you could, you would need to ensure the container injects the same instance over the course of the request, but each instance is isolated across requests.

Comment: @ChrisHardie - Most IoC containers can bind to concrete instances as well, and you can add an interface to your own own DbContext quite easily if you really want to.  ie. `MyContext : DbContext, IMyContext` so that's not really an issue.  Configuring containers to use PerWebRequest object lifetimes is also pretty trivial, and the way it's usually done.

Answer (score 7):

Setting up Unity for ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI is quite easy if you install and add the `Unity.Mvc*` and `Unity.WebAPI*` Nuget packages to your project. (The `*` is a version number, like 3 or 4 or 5. Look for the appropriate versions for your project. Here are for example the links [to the Unity.Mvc 5 package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc5/) and [to the Untity.WebAPI 5 package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.WebAPI/).)

The usage of these packages is explained in [this blog post](http://netmvc.blogspot.de/2012/04/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html).

The building blocks are roughly like so:

You build a unity container and register all your dependencies there, especially the EF context:

```
private static IUnityContainer BuildContainer()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterType<MyContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

    container.RegisterType<IOrderService, OrderService>();
    container.RegisterType<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
    container.RegisterType<IEmailMessenger, EmailMessenger>();
    // etc., etc.

    return container;
}
```

`MyContext` is your derived `DbContext` class. Registering the context with the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` is very important because it will ensure that a new context per web request will be instantiated and disposed by the container at the end of each request.

If you don't have interfaces for your services but just concrete classes you can remove the lines above that register the interfaces. If a service needs to be injected into a controller Unity will just create an instance of your concrete service class.

Once you have built the container you can register it as dependency resolver for MVC and WebAPI in `Application_Start` in `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var container = ...BuildContainer();

    // MVC
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
        new Unity.MvcX.UnityDependencyResolver(container));

    // WebAPI
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
        new Unity.WebApiX.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

Once the `DependencyResolver`s are set the framework is able to instantiate controllers that take parameters in their constructor if the parameters can be resolved with the registered types. For example, you can create a `CustomerController` now that gets a `CustomerService` and an `EmailMessenger` injected:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;
    private readonly IEmailMessenger _emailMessenger;

    public CustomerController(
        ICustomerService customerService,
        IEmailMessenger emailMessenger)
    {
        _customerService = customerService;
        _emailMessenger = emailMessenger;
    }

    // now you can interact with _customerService and _emailMessenger
    // in your controller actions
}
```

The same applies to derived `ApiController`s for WebAPI.

The services can take a dependency on the context instance to interact with Entity Framework, like so:

```
public class CustomerService // : ICustomerService
{
    private readonly MyContext _myContext;

    public CustomerService(MyContext myContext)
    {
        _myContext = myContext;
    }

    // now you can interact with _myContext in your service methods
}
```

When the MVC/WebAPI framework instantiates a controller it will inject the registered service instances and resolve their own dependencies as well, i.e. inject the registered context into the service constructor. All services you will inject into the controllers will receive the same context instance during a single request.

With this setup you usually don't need a `context = new MyContext()` nor a `context.Dispose()` as the IOC container will manage the context lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using a repository then I assume you would have some place to write your logic/processing that your service operation would use. I would create a new instance of the Context in that logic/process class method and use its methods directly. Finally, dispose it off right after its use probably under a "using".

The processing method would eventually transform the returned/processed data into a data/message contract which the service returns to the controller.

Keep the data logic completely separate from Controller. Also keep the view model separate from data contract.

Answer (score 0):

If you move ahead with this architecture, you are going to be tightly coupling the Entity Framework with either your service or your controller. The repository abstraction gives you a couple things:

1) You are able to easily swap out data access technologies in the future

2) You are able to mock out your data store, allowing you to easily unit test your data access code

You are wondering where to put your EF context. One of the benefits of using the Entity Framework is that all operations on it are enrolled into a transaction. You need to ensure that any data access code uses the same context to enjoy this benefit.

The design pattern that solves that problem is the Unit of Work pattern, which by the looks of things, you are already using. I strongly recommend continuing to use it. Otherwise, you will need to initialize your context in your controller, pass it to your service, which will need to pass it to any other service it interacts with.

Looking at the objects you have listed, it appears to be a considerate attempt to build this app with enterprise architectural best practices. While abstractions do introduce complexity, there is no doubting the benefit they provide.

Comment: Most people are unlikely to change their data access technology, and it's quite easy to mock EF (especially 6+, which offers special support for this) simply by deriving your dbcontext from an interface as well as the DbContext.  Even if they might change their data access technology, it takes a lot of effort to avoid introducing coupling to the technology, even when using a repository (Generic Repository is huge culprit here, because they usually pass linq queries directly, and these are typically very tightly coupled)